# Use regex to match a number between 1 and 105

Tags: regex

I've tried several options without success.

```
(105)|(0*\d{1,2})
```

This is where I go?

Comment: what language or environment are you using ?

Comment: What is the `125` supposed to do there? Btw, don't try to use regex for maths - use a regex for the format and a different condition for the range

Comment: I you already know its a number why would you use RegEx for this? RegEx is for finding things in text not numbers.

Comment: it's an interesting problem still because it has practical applications, i.e. searching a logfile for a specific number, and is interesting from a theoretical perspective: the lexicographical ordering and the order of the integers don't match up so you have to break it down into cases.

Comment: Is to find all the numbers within the value in a text file. In Perl

Comment: why use regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the answer above `/10[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2}/` but it is not anchored so it will match things like 990 and 1051.  It will match as a regexp I mean.

To anchor the regexp use ^ at the start and $ at the end.  Here's an improved version of the answer

```
/^(10[0-5]|\d{1,2})$/
```

I've used `\d` which is a commonly available shortcut for [0-9] digits

Edit: see tripleee's comment below, also needs ( ) to group the two alternate expressions

Comment: You've anchored to the line, though.  It won't match numbers in the middle of lines, in case that is needed:

Comment: @John I've made the assumption that "just accept numbers" means no other input so "hahaha 101 banana" is rejected.  I believe this is implied by the question

Comment: The regex is still wrong, you need more anchors or parentheses, i.e. `^10[0-5]$|^\d{1,2}$` or `^(10[0-5]|\d{1,2})$`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this:

```
/\b0*([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|10[0-5])\b/
```

Comment: You should put start and end of string matches at the beginning and end of the regExp. My take would be `/^0*(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|10[0-5])$/` assuming the range is inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

> /10[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2}/

- 10[0-5]: matches '100' to '105' inclusive
- [0-9]{1,2}: matches ranges '00' to '99' and '0' to '9'

Comment: +1 voted up, and added some value to your answer, through my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a match evaluator and check for any condition you want.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the better one:

```
\b0*(10[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2})\b
```

Takes care of leading Zeros.